# How to access variable from Closure Scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

How to access the closure scope variables in inner function in JavaScript.

I want to access **UL** variable in **`setTimeout`** function.

```
    ul.find("li").each(function (a, ele) {

        $(ele).attr("tabindex", options.items[a].tabindex);

        $(ele).on("focusout", function () {

            setTimeout(function () {
                **//ACCESS UL HERE**
                debugger;
            }, 1);

        }.bind(ul,ele));
    }.bind(ul));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`closure`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in `setTimeout`

> `Closures` 'remember' the environment in which they were created.

```
ul.find("li").each(function(a, ele) {
  $(ele).attr("tabindex", options.items[a].tabindex);
  $(ele).on("focusout", function() {
      setTimeout(function(ul) {
        return function() {
          console.log(ul);
        }
      })(ul), 1);
  }.bind(ul, ele));
}.bind(ul));
```

Comment: @ShanKhan, I will prefer not to answer ;) You are suppose to understand both `Closures` as well as `Function#bind` to make any move..Both have totally different purpose.. ;)

Comment: can you give me a good link that provides a fundamental different purpose so i can understand, i have seen examples but those can be performed by both.

Answer (score 0):

It works normally. The scope of the `ul` is valid inside the `setTimeout` function.

```
ul.find("li").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("tabindex", options.items[a].tabindex)
    .on("focusout", function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        ul.css('color', 'orange');
      }, 1);
    });
});
```

A simple code like this will explain you:

```js
(function s() {
  var a = "hi";
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(a);
  }, 1000);
})();
```

Here, the `ul` is the same as the `a` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use access the UL by finding the parent of current element. For getting the immediate parent with specified type, you can use `.closest()` method

```
$(ele).on("focusout", function() {
   var el = $(this);
   setTimeout(function() {
     el.closest("ul");
     debugger;
   }, 1);

 }.bind(ul, ele));
```